# Vue component event after render

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

Is there an event in Vue that gets fired after an element re-renders? I have an object that updates, which causes my template to update. After it updates I want to trigger an event which runs a jQuery function. The code looks like this:

```
template: `
    <div class="undo-margin">
        <div class="gradient">
            <img v-bind:src="blogPost.thumbnail"/>
            <h1 class="align-bottom">{{blogPost.title}}</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container bg-faded">
            <article v-html="blogPost.article"></article>
        </div>
    </div>

`,
props: ["blogid"],
data: function () {
    return blogPageData;
},
mounted: function () {
    const blogid = jQuery("#blogPage").attr("blogid");
    if (this.authdata.roles.indexOf("Administrator") !== -1) {
        this.isAdmin = true;
    }

    this.getBlogPost(blogid);
},
methods: {
    getBlogPost: function (blogid) {
        var element = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: `/api/blog/${blogid}`,
            type: "get",
            headers: headers,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === undefined) {
                    window.location.replace("/blog");
                } else {
                    element.isDetails = true;
                    element.blogPost = data;
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                window.location.replace("/blog");
                errorData.error = data.responseText;
            }
        });
    }
},
watch: {
    blogPost: function () {
        console.log(this.blogPost);
        jQuery("pre").each((i, e) => {
            hljs.highlightBlock(e);
        });
    }
}
```

As you see, I tried using the watch event, however when the watch event triggers, my page is not updated yet. blogPost however has been changed, but vue is still rendering the page. I know I could theoretically fix this by adding a setTimeout, but I would prefer something cleaner.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`updated` might be what you're looking for.

Vue2 https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

Edit: Now that Vue3 is the current version here are the links to the relevant lifecycle hooks.

Vue3 Composition API https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onupdated

Vue3 Options API https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#updated

Comment: thank you, this does work. I also found out that you can use `this.$nextTick(function () {...});` to execute code after updating the DOM. I'll leave it here in case somebody finds it useful as well

Comment: Be aware that in some environments `updated()` will not get called when you refresh your page:

See "This hook is not called during server-side rendering" at
https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated.

Answer (score 27):

[updated()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) should be what you're looking for:

> Called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched.
>
> The component’s DOM will have been updated when this hook is called, so you can perform DOM-dependent operations here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Vue 3**, you can utilize the nextTick() method. This method takes a callback, which will be called after the DOM has been updated due to a state change.

I have a similar situation where I need to trigger a change event on an element with jQuery on a legacy app. In my case I'm handling an event dispatched in a child component. Here's a rough example of my use case.

```
<template>
  <childComponent @valueChanged="triggerElementChange"/>
  <input ref="element" type="hidden" name="elementName"/>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref, nextTick} from 'vue'
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'

// reference to element I want to trigger change on
// (identified by ref attribute with matching name)
const element = ref(null)

function triggerElementChange(){
  // state updated via child component prior to emitting valueChanged event

  // wait until DOM is updated, then trigger jQuery change event on referenced element
  nextTick(() => {
    $(element.value).change()
  })
}
</script>
```